# Renaming a model property causes an error when updating the database with temporal tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

I have an EF Core 6 context that uses temporal tables, and am trying to rename one of the properties on a model.

I have a model that was named `PropertyGroupsInvestors`, which I renamed to `Investment`. That worked fine.

I then noticed that the `InvestorPayment` model had the following...

```cs
  public int PropertyGroupsInvestorsID { get; set; }
  public PropertyGroupsInvestors PropertyGroupsInvestors { get; set; } = new();
```

...which should also have been renamed. I renamed the two properties as follows...

```cs
  public int InvestmentsID { get; set; }
  public Investment Investment { get; set; } = new();
```

...and added a migration.

However, when I tried to update the database, it failed with the error "*Setting SYSTEM_VERSIONING to ON failed because table 'MyProject.dbo.InvestorPayments' has 10 columns and table 'MyProject.dbo.InvestorPaymentsHistory' has 9 columns*."

Looking in SQL Server Management Studio, I can see that both the `InvestorPayments` and corresponding history tables have both the old `PropertyGroupsInvestorsID` column and the new `InvestmentId` column. They both have 10 columns, so I'm not sure what he message means though. See the screenshot...

[image]

Any idea how I fix this? Ideally I need to get rid of the `PropertyGroupsInvestorsID` column from both tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with the **renaming** of columns in the system versioning table using a code-first approach. So a quick solution (if you don't want to drop temporal tables) can be just to create two migrations. One migration to add a new column, and the second migration to remove the old column.

So first migration will contain both, **PropertyGroupsInvestorsID** and **InvestorsID** and then remove **PropertyGroupsInvestorsID** to create a new migration.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. Too late for this project as gave up on the temporal tables (see my comment on @Alv's answer), but it's worth keeping in mind for the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem here like deleting or modifying one field, it looks like when you have a system-versioned table, you can't modify the structure because it's linked to the history table.

Using SQL server doesn't look like there is any problem:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/add-columns-to-a-table-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks, I came to the conclusion that, nice as temporal tables are, they just aren't worth the hassle when using EF Core. I dropped them all and rebuilt my database (thankfully I'm still in development) and all works fine now. Shame, maybe one day

Comment: If I try to rename one field from my code to the DB, when I tried to update it I got this error: " There is already an object named 'tableName' in the database"

Comment: yeah, I had similar (and other) problems. That's why I ended up dropping them. They look really powerful, but I don't think EF can handle them properly yet. Thanks