# Applying a rename migration with a Temporal Table gets SqlException (0x80131904) mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, database-migration, temporal-tables

We have a model-first approach in a recently migrated project from .NET5 to .NET8 and to EF 6. Our model has an entity with a SQL Server Temporal Table related.

The problem arises when we want to rename a column/property from our entity. The migration script is generated with a call to the `sp_rename` store procedure but we get:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

I think this script is not handling the fact that the related temporal table has to be migrated too.

We generate the migration-script and tried to apply it directly to the DB and obviously we got the same error.

This is a completely new column, so we decided to drop it a recreate it but with a different context this would not be possible.

Any ideas about it?

Comment: Disabling the Temporal Table allows us to apply the migration to the entity table

Comment: Strange, it should be working (or you should be getting different errors). Did you trace what kind of sql statements are executed during your migration? Some relevant links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038735/renaming-a-model-property-causes-an-error-when-updating-the-database-with-tempor

Comment: Did you check if user has appropriate permission to execute sp_rename. Might be the reason. Also can you make sure transaction is committing properly by verifying generated script.

Comment: Yes, I checked the generated script. It is a standard rename completely generated by EF, an execution of the SQL Server sp_rename store procedure. I do not believe it is a problem of permissions, this is not the first column rename migration, I alreday renamed columns in not Versioned tables without any problems, also taking into account the error code

Comment: @siggemannen thanks for the provided link, in that case, the error is different but it makes me think about the fact that the handling of  Temporals was rewritten in EF6. As I pointed out, I started with an upgrade from NET 5 to NET 8. The Temporal Tables configuration with code first approach has completely changed to enforce the use of Shadow Properties and a different way of configuration to handle the system versioning. Maybe a misconfiguration is the reason that EF does not know that there is already a temporal table and does not generate the proper script for the column rename migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that I think of. The key step is to disable system versioning, apply the schema changes, and then re-enable system versioning.

```
ALTER TABLE YourMainTable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);

sp_rename 'YourMainTable.OldColumnName', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';
sp_rename 'YourHistoryTable.OldColumnName', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';

ALTER TABLE YourMainTable 
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.YourHistoryTable, DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON));
```

**Update:**
EF6 doesn't inherently support SQL Server temporal tables directly within its migrations or model configuration. The above solution to manually alter the system versioning during migrations is currently the most straightforward approach to managing schema changes involving temporal tables in EF6.

However, you may still automate this process with EF6 by adding some custom scripts in migration. Inside your migration's `Up()` and `Down()` methods, you can use the `Sql()` method to run raw SQL commands that implement the steps outlined above.

**Ex:**

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("ALTER TABLE YourMainTable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);");

    Sql("EXEC sp_rename 'YourMainTable.OldColumnName', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';");
    Sql("EXEC sp_rename 'YourHistoryTable.OldColumnName', 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';");

    Sql("ALTER TABLE YourMainTable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.YourHistoryTable, DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON));");
}

public override void Down()
{
    
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works. As I mentioned in the first comment on the question, disabling the system versioning does the work, but this implies a manual handling of the migration. I was expecting EF to do this for me. Maybe because of a misconfiguration during the framework upgrade from NET5 to NET8, EF can not know the existence of the versioning, or maybe there is no way to make these changes without manually disabling the versioning. I will continue to check the configuration and EF docs to see if there is an automatic way to do it.

Comment: Gotcha! That makes sense. Please check my updated answer and see if that helps.